# Matrix Linearity and Orthogonal Vector Question Help

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

**Question One:** Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ $\in \mathbb{R^n}$. Let S be the set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$ that are orthogonal to both $v_1$ and $v_2$. That is, $S=\{x\in \mathbb{R^n}: x*v_1=0$ and $ x*v_2=0\}$. Is $S$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$?

*My attempted solution:* This may sound like a silly question but I'm not very sure why S would form a subspace for $\mathbb{R^n}$ in this case. If three vectors are to form a subspace for $\mathbb{R^3}$ for example, does it mean that the three vectors have to span $\mathbb{R^3}$ or does it simply mean that these three vectors exist in the $\mathbb{R^3}$ space while they might be dependent of each other? In other words, if three vectors are to span $\mathbb{R^2}$, can they still be a subspace for $\mathbb{R^3}$?

**Question Two:** Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices. Suppose that the first column of $AB$ is entirely zero, but the first column of B is not entirely zero, then which of the following are true?

1. There is not enough information on columns of A
2. $det(A)$ does not equal zero
3. The columns of A are linearly dependent
4. $det(A)$ cannot be computed with the given information

*My attempted solution:* For this question, I'm actually quite confused. The correct answer is #3 where the columns of A are linearly dependent. How exactly can this be proved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the definitions of what a subspace is. If $x_1, x_2 \in S$ is $x_1 + x_2 \in S$ as well? If $c \in \mathbb{R}$ then is $c x_1 \in S$?

Answer (score 1):

What the first question is trying to differentiate is between a "subset" and a "subspace". The span of a finite number of vectors is always going to be a "subset" of the vector space due to closure, but it is not necessarily a "subspace" because then the subset would need to have the additional restrictions that would qualify it to be a subspace

Using your example, if three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ span $S = \mathbb{R}^2$, it is indeed a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, as it is a subset which is also in itself a vector space

For the second question, it requires looking at matrix multiplication as a linear combination of vectors

Let $A$ be composed of $n$ column vectors of dimension $n$, similarly for B, such that

$$A = [\textbf{a}_1, \textbf{a}_2, \textbf{a}_3,..., \textbf{a}_n]$$
$$B = [\textbf{b}_1, \textbf{b}_2,\textbf{b}_3,  ..., \textbf{b}_n]$$

Now, when we do the matrix multiplication $AB$, we can write it as

$$AB = [\textbf{x}_1, \textbf{x}_2,\textbf{x}_3,...,\textbf{x}_n]$$

where

$$\textbf{x}_i = \sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij}\textbf{a}_j$$

Here, $b_{ij}$ is the $j^{th}$ element of the column vector $\textbf{b}_i$

Can you see why the C option is right now?